# AngularJS: How do I bi-directionally bind to the parent scope property without using an attribute?

Tags: angularjs

So I want to do what I did in this question: 
[AngularJS: Two way data binding fails if element has ngModel and a directive with a local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632042/angularjs-two-way-data-binding-fails-if-element-has-ngmodel-and-a-directive-wit)

but without using an attibute value to bind. I've tried using just an equals sign

```
scope: {bindToParent: '='},
```

but it doesn't seem to work? Can someone change this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ews7S/1/  to show me how I can directly bind to the parent property without having to use an attribute in the element?

Comment: What attribute are you trying not to use in the parent?  and what parent property are you trying to bind to in the child scope/directive?  
If you use just '=', Angular expects the parent scope to have an attribute with the same name -- hence 'bindToparent' in your case, which doesn't exist in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your fiddle:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" dir="123">
```

If you want `dir` to not have a value, well, `dir` doesn't need a value.  This works as well in your fiddle:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" dir>
```