# What are the undocumented features of Angular?

Tags: angularjs

The Angular documentation is missing a few things.  Can someone summarize what the undocumented features are?

Comment: They're not undocumented anymore, though ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Angular 1.0.5 and 1.0.4:**

- [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#Properties) has two useful undocumented properties:

  1. `$parent` - can be used as a hack for binding to a primitive property in a parent scope - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850702/215945)
  2. `$$phase` - can be used to determine if a $digest is already in progress - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859093/215945)
- [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch#Parameters) has an undocumented `change` parameter that accepts an expression ([example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HpTRNv?p=preview))
- [select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) has an undocumented `ng-change` parameter that accepts an expression
- [Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes#Methods) has an undocumented `$observe` method (although it is mentioned on the [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes) page)
- [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory) has two undocumented methods ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/yYEXN/))

  1. `get()`
  2. `info()`
- the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) service has two undocumented events

  1. `$locationChangeStart(evt, newUrl, oldUrl)`  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13918833/215945))
  2. `$locationChangeSuccess(evt, newUrl, oldUrl)` (see also [What's the difference between $locationChangeSuccess and $locationChangeStart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006849/angularjs-whats-the-difference-between-locationchangesuccess-and-locationch))
- use ng-value (undocumented) with `input type="radio"`, see [Disqus comment](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.radio#comment-880774822) in API docs