# How to watch for a route change in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would one watch/trigger an event on a route change?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

**Note**: This is a proper answer for a legacy version of AngularJS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event) for updated versions.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function($event, next, current) { 
   // ... you could trigger something here ...
 });
```

The following events are also available (their callback functions take different arguments):

- $routeChangeSuccess
- $routeChangeError
- $routeUpdate - if [reloadOnSearch](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.$routeProvider#when) property has been set to false

See the [$route](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.$route) docs.

There are two other [undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700325/what-are-the-undocumented-features-of-angular) events:

- $locationChangeStart
- $locationChangeSuccess

See [What's the difference between $locationChangeSuccess and $locationChangeStart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006849/angularjs-whats-the-difference-between-locationchangesuccess-and-locationch)

Comment: You also need to inject "$route" somewhere or these events never fire.

Comment: `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` are now documented! http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location

Comment: @KevinBeal thank you, thank you, *thank you*. I was going bananas trying to work out why these events didn't fire.

Comment: Just a note for everyone using $state, instead of $route. In that case you need to inject $state and use $stateChangeStart.

Comment: It's `$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {` now.

Comment: what's the difference between $locationChangeSuccess and $routeChangeSuccess

Comment: This is ok, works perfect, but, I have problems when the URL is changed by the next and previous actions fo the browser... Works perfect when I use href or any location thing on my angular app, but crash with navigator actions.. any suggest?

Comment: Not sure how you are putting this code. Is this in a controller? How are you injecting $scope into your method?

Comment: thanks @J.P.tenBerge `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess`  worked for me on angularjs 1.4.6

Answer (score 31):

If you don't want to place the watch inside a specific controller, you can add the watch for the whole aplication in Angular app [`run()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 
        // handle route changes     
    });
});
```

Comment: I love it when I come across an answer like this and find something I didn't know about like .run() although this is not where I needed the event listener in my particular use case, it is very useful to me.  Thanks Zanon!

Comment: i am learning angular. so i need to know what kind of info we can get from event, next, current argument ?

Answer (score 11):

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  //..do something
  //event.stopPropagation();  //if you don't want event to bubble up 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  //if you want to interrupt going to another location.
  event.preventDefault();  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the suggested solutions did not work for me using *$routeChangeStart* event

If you run into the same problem, try:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
   // ... you could trigger something here ...
 });
```

In my configuration I'm using @ui-router/angularjs (a.k.a angular-ui-router) from node package manager (a.k.a npm)

Answer (score -1):

This is for the total beginner... like me:

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Info"> Info </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Angular:

```
//Create App
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

//Configure routes
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({ template: "<p>Coming soon</p>" })
      .when("/", {
        template: "<p>Home information</p>"
      })
      .when("/Info", {
        template: "<p>Basic information</p>"
        //templateUrl: "/content/views/Info.html"
      });
});

//Controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
  $scope.location = $location.path();
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
    console.log("routeChangeStart");
   //Place code here:....
   });
});
```

Hope this helps a total beginner like me. Here is the full working sample:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Info"> Info </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
//Create App
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

//Configure routes
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({ template: "<p>Coming soon</p>" })
      .when("/", {
        template: "<p>Home information</p>"
      })
      .when("/Info", {
        template: "<p>Basic information</p>"
        //templateUrl: "/content/views/Info.html"
      });
});

//Controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
  $scope.location = $location.path();
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
    console.log("routeChangeStart");
   //Place code here:....
   });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```