# Get stateParams on change without reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm making an app using the angular ui router.

When navigating to a particular state, which always has parameters passed to it, I need to be able to change the url and update the parameters without reloading the view.

In my state config I'm using:
    reloadOnSearch: false

This works and allows me to update the parameters in the URL without page reload.

However, I need to be notified of these changes on the $stateParams so I can run various methods that will do things with the new data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, James

Comment: you can do $scope.$watch on $stateParams

Comment: Can you fire off a change function on the `$routeUpdate` event? It should be broadcast on a URL update wen `reloadOnSearch` is `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relevant to me so I did a bit of work.

Here is my state that uses `reloadOnSearch` but fires off a function each time the URL is updated.

```
      .state('route2.list', {
          url: "/list/:listId",
          templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
          reloadOnSearch: false,
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams);
            $scope.listId = $stateParams.listId;
            $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
            //This will fire off every time you update the URL.
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) { 
                $scope.listId = 22;
                console.log("Update");
                console.log($location.url()); 
                console.log($stateParams);    
                });
          }
      }
```

Returns in console:

```
Update
/route2/list/7 (index):70
Object {listId: "8"} (index):71
```

`$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` should get you where you want to go. Keep in mind that your location functions will always fire off, even on the first load.

Inspiration taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event) SO post and the `$location` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

**EDIT 2**
According to the Angular docs for `ngRoute`, `$routeParams` aren't updated until after the success of the changes. Chances are that ui-route has a similar restriction. Since we're inturrupting the resolution of the state, `$stateParams` is never updated.  What you can do is just emulate how `$stateParams` are passed in the first place using `$urlMatcherFactory`.

Like so:

```
      .state('route2.list', {
          url: "/list/:listId",
          templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
          reloadOnSearch: false,
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $urlMatcherFactory){
            console.log($stateParams.listId + " :: " + $location.url());
            $scope.listId = $stateParams.listId;
            $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) { 
                $scope.listId = 22;
                //For when you want to dynamically assign arguments for .compile
                console.log($state.get($state.current).url); //returns /list/:listId
                //plain text for the argument for clarity
                var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/route2/list/:listId");
                //below returns Object {listId: "11" when url is "/list/11"} 
                console.log(urlMatcher.exec($location.url())); 
                var matched = urlMatcher.exec($location.url());
                //this line will be wrong unless we set $stateParams = matched
                console.log("Update " + $stateParams.listId);
                console.log($location.url());
                //properly updates scope.
                $scope.listId = matched.listId;
                });
          }
      })
```

The scope actually updates, so that's a good thing. The thing to remember is that you're stoppng the normal resolution of everything but setting `reloadOnSearch` to `false` so you'll need to handle pretty much everything on your own.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to help me.. This is certainly a step in the right direction. So now I have an event to play with, how can i get the new parameters after change? $stateParams isnt updated

Comment: Location is still available to you if you pass it in. You can get the route using its functions, or something similar. Note the by using `$locationChangeStart` and `reloadOnSearch` you're pretty much stopping any scope updates. `$scope.$apply()` will likely be your friend with this as well. Also, you need to use `$locationChangeSuccess` if you want the final URL.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but i need to return an object like the $stateParams obj. Doesn't angular-ui have some sort of method that actually gets the stateparams?

Comment: Edit 2 is up. Even if someone comes along with a one line way to do this, I learned quite a bit about how ui-router works.

Comment: Roman! Thanks so much this is exactly what I'm looking for! I'll put this in a service :)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Romans code, i built a service that returns the state params of of the current state

```
/**
 * Get parameters from URL and return them as an object like in ui-router
 */
eventaApp.service( 'getStateParams', ['$urlMatcherFactory', '$location', '$state', function(     $urlMatcherFactory, $location, $state ){
  return function() {

    var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile($state.current.url);
    return urlMatcher.exec($location.url());

  }

}]);
```