# How to prevent user to change state of route before some processes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have Principle factory that set and get user value from local storage after login. But when the user first logged in Principle factory return firstLogin = true, if the user first logged in user must update their company. Because while registering process, the application creates an empty company model and I have to update it with source and addresses information at the first login.

So, how could I prevent user to change state by clicking over URL hrefs at navigation?

P.S

I already tried to add ng-disable= 'firstLogin' but i have a lot of states of the application. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to disable ui-router disable for all links?

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event ?

Comment: It is helpful but I'm trying to solve with ui-router library so $stateChangeStart solved. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$stateChangeStart`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) or [`$routeChangeStart`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) depending whether you are using `ui-router` or `ng-router` respectively.

You can run some functions like checking for `auth` etc before a `state/route` change occurs. Please check the examples in the docs linked.