# prevent next state Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I do that with ui-router? In ui-router I'm using this syntax :

router

```
.when('/login',{
    templateUrl:'app/view/page/users/login.html',
    isLogged:true
})
```

app run

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(event,next) {
    if(next.$$route.isLogged){
        console.log('...')
    }
})
```

I tried change route to state in ui-router but I get `isLogged undefined`. How can I solve that?

Comment: You probably just need to use event.preventDefault();

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event TL;DR Instead of `$routeChangeStart` use `$locationChangeStart`

Comment: Hello. Why you don't use $routeProvider 'resolve' or 'redirectTo' or 'resolveRedirectTo ' I think this is more simple way.

Comment: Fixed. My mistake.