# AngularJs : Cancel route resolve without promise

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I need to cancel my route in case of wrong login, this is my ANGULARJS **NG-ROUTE** code :

```
monApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    var rsf = { // This function tells if user is logged or not
        "check":function(stockeUtilisateur,$location,Notification){
            u = stockeUtilisateur.getUtilisateur();

                if(u.role=='admin'||u.role=='utilisateur'){
                    Notification.success("Youre logged");
                }
                else{ 
                     $location.path('/accueil');     //redirect user to home.
                    Notification.error("bad password");
                }
        }
    };

    $routeProvider
    .when('/accueil', {
      templateUrl: 'vues/accueil.html',
      controller: 'neutreCtrl'
    })
    .when('/compte', {
      templateUrl: 'vues/compte.html',
      controller: 'compteCtrl',
      resolve:rsf 
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/accueil'}); 
})
```

The problem is that I don't want to use `$location.path()` in the case of login fail, because it reloads the whole page while I simply need to stay on the route and simply cancel the route, as long as user login is wrong.

I don't know what code I could use, I've tried this instead of `$location.path()` : `event.preventDefault();` but it doesn't work.

I've also tried `resolve.cancel();` but it doesn't work too, snif !

If I remove `$location.path()`, then the resolve still works and i can see the "compte" view  while the user is not logged.

IN other words, i don't want to get redirected, but i'd like resolve to simply do  nothing in case of bad password.

Maybe you have an idea ?

Thank you .

Comment: I am not confident enough to post an answer, but quick research says to use prevent default on `$locationChangeStart` event. https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event

Comment: I would echo what @Jordan.J.D said, leverage the router events.  You will most likely have to store the login info *some place* **temporarily** in order to check it during the event handler.  But be sure to delete that data regardless of login success/failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't want to use $location.path() in the case of login fail, because it reloads the whole page while I simply need to stay on the route and simply cancel the route, as long as user login is wrong.

To cancel a route change from a resolver function, use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw):

```
monApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    var rsf = { // This function tells if user is logged or not
        "check":function(stockeUtilisateur,$location,Notification){
            u = stockeUtilisateur.getUtilisateur();

                if(u.role=='admin'||u.role=='utilisateur'){
                    Notification.success("Youre logged");
                }
                else{ 
                    //$location.path('/accueil'); 
                    //Notification.error("bad password");
                    throw "bad bassword";
                }
        }
    };

    $routeProvider
    .when('/accueil', {
      templateUrl: 'vues/accueil.html',
      controller: 'neutreCtrl'
    })
    .when('/compte', {
      templateUrl: 'vues/compte.html',
      controller: 'compteCtrl',
      resolve:rsf 
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/accueil'}); 
})
```

When a resolver function throws an error, the route change is prevented and a [`$routeChangeError` event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) is broadcast.