# $routeProvider - not load controller after failed resolve

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'd like to check something in router. In some condition I should redirect on anothter page.

I set up router:

```
when('/login', {
 templateUrl: 'login.html',
 controller: 'Login',
 resolve : {
   'checkLogin': ['checkLogin', function(checkLogin){
      return checkLogin.isLogin();
    }]
 }
})
```

And factory:

```
app.factory('checkLogin', [function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        isLogin: function() {
            if (loggin === 1) {
               $location.path('/home');
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

And If `loggin === 1` it redirects to `/home`, but it calls `Login` controller anyway. How can I disable it? Do not fire `Login` controller in this case?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *but it calls Login controller anyway. How can I disable it? Do not fire Login controller in this case?*

Comment: @PankajParkar I mean If user is logged in I need to redirect to `/home`, and I don't need run `Login` controller. Inside `Login` controller I call API. I checked - app redirects to `/home` and calls that API at the same time. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Also I added `console.log('this is login controller')` inside `Login` controller. App redirects me to `/home` and I can see `this is login controller` in my console.

Comment: Why don't you use that factory in your controller ? Since resolve part of the route is to provide data for controller so controller calls after resolve

Comment: @Nick you could think of shift your implementation in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346403/2435473) with resolve way you can't cancel your current navigation

Comment: @PankajParkar, got it. Thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar is it possible to use promise inside `$locationChangeStart`? `if (loggin === 1)` was example, I call API `$http('/api/islogin'...)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use `$locationChangeStart` advised by @PankajParkar.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    "use strict";
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (next.indexOf('login') !== -1) {
            if (loggin === 1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/home');
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Not sure it looks good.