# How do I keep the link marked as 'active' after the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Using 'ngRoute', There are 3 different links on the page, each directs to its own ng-view using different controllers, when clicked on a specific link, 
a function runs which strips off 'active' class from all the links and put 'active' class on the cliced link.

THE PROBLEM:
after i choose a specific link, it gets highlighted because of the 'active' class.
BUT when I REFRESH the page, everything goes fine, I'm still on the ng-view i need
BUT.. the 'activated link' is no longer highlighted, and the default link is.

```
bookApp.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $scope, $route) {
  $scope.setActive = function(event) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul li a');        
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
        links[i].className = '';
    }
    angular.element(event.target).parent().addClass('active');
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the active class on the element based on the route instead of the doing it dynamically when you click on the link?  In other words the controller reads the route and sets the className accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply, Could you please give me a code example im pretty new.

Comment: It is because you are highlighting the link in your setActive function. I assume that function only gets called when clicked. As @robbymurphy stated, set your class based off of `$route`. Start by simply `console.log($route)` to see if there is something there to help you

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, could you please send me a hint or external resourses?

Comment: You can start here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples instead of putting your code in a click function try the `$routeChange` events

Comment: I'll give it a try, first time im debugging! ;D

Comment: Also, give this thread a peek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event

Comment: I give up, could you please give me the solution?

Comment: I've heard, i can use SessionStorage, any thoughts?

Comment: In my case, there is js which is filled with JQuery functions. And I used `$(window).on('hashchange')` because url of mine has regular pattern can be separated by first hash like `/user_id/profile`, `/user_id/blogs`, `/user_id/photos` and etc. So I caught this point and used this to activate tabs. There are several ways to solve this and I think this is not bad way when we are using proper url pattern.