# Setting <h1> based on URL string in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am getting unidentified on my function when trying to set the `<h1>` based on a function using the URL string. This is my code so far, I would set it up in Plunker, but is a little awkward as there I can't replicate a URL change:

```
angular.module('app').controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

  // Create <h1> based on url string

  var pageUrl = $location.url().substring(1);

  $scope.pageTitleItems = {
    feedback: "Feedback",
    settings: "Settings",
    editprofile: "Edit Profile"
  };

  $scope.$watch('$scope.location.url()', function(newValue, oldValue, $location) {

    $scope.pageTitle = $scope.pageTitleItems.pageUrl;

    console.log($scope.pagetitle);

  });

});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?!

Comment: you're watching `'$scope.location.url()'`, though in the code shown, no `$scope.location` is ever defined?

Comment: I see what you mean, though I have now changed that to '$scope.$location.url()', which is part of angular, so shouldn't need defining, from what I understand.

Comment: That's not quite correct, even though you have `$location` injected, it's still not part of your `$scope` and thus not "watchable". At the very least you would have to assign it to `$scope` like `$scope.location = $location;` and change the watch expression to something like `...$watch('location'...` (without `$scope`!), though I'd say this is really far off best practise. Try @marcoseu's answer, it's the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for anyone who needs this functionality:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $location.path(); }, function(newValue, oldValue) {

    var pageUrl = $location.path().substring(1);

    var pageTitleItems = {
      feedback: "Feedback",
      settings: "Settings",
      editprofile: "Edit Profile"
    };

    $scope.pageTitle = pageTitleItems[pageUrl];

    console.log('page url ' + pageUrl);

    console.log('page title ' + $scope.pageTitle);  

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid comma:

```
$scope.pageTitleItems = {
    feedback: "Feedback",
    settings: "Settings",
    editprofile: "Edit Profile",  // <-- remove that comma
  };
```

Also, you will probably want to watch for route changes:

[How to watch for a route change in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/angularjs-how-to-watch-for-a-route-change)

And finally this might help:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, cur, prev) {
    ...do what you have to do here, maybe set a $rootScope.path as you did
})
```

And specific to your code, you may want to define:

```
$scope.location = $location
```

so that your watch has something to watch.

Comment: Ah that is true, though still returning undefined. : (

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can `$watch` for changes in `$scope.location.url()` and your best bet is use $routeChangeStart as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/angular-js-redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition).  I tried to watch for `$location.path()` and `$location.url()` and they all return undefined.

If I understood you correctly, you want to set the H1 based on the URL of your current path.  If that is the case, have you tried simply putting the `$scope.pageTitle = $scope.pageTitleItems.pageUrl;` directly in the controller (ie: outside of $scope.$watch)?

Comment: I have got a bit further with this now, but I still get 'undefined' on using the string created from 'var pageUrl = $location.path().substring(1);', it does return the correct string, but doesn't then affect the '$scope' when using it in combination with '$scope.pageTitle = $scope.pageTitleItems.pageUrl;'