# How to read the multiple parameter values from url in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read multiple parameters from the url in angularjs? I am able to get the first parameter target as 34 but the second parameter is coming as undefined.

Comment: I am trying to read multiple parameters from the url in angularjs? I tried the following url http://localhost:48716/#?target=34#?testvalue=95

  $rootScope.$watch('location.search()', function () {
        $rootScope.target = ($location.search()).target;
        $rootScope.testvalue= ($location.search()).testvalue;

           }, true);

I am able to get the first parameter target as 34 but the second parameter is coming as undefined.

Comment: Add this into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

You are not using #, ? etc the standard way and the angularJS will obviously not get what is meant by your URL params. There can only be one # and ? in the URL. Just learn about location hash, query strings etc and then the code might work correctly.

May be the URL should be localhost:48716/#?target=34&testvalue=95

**old answer**

You could use the $routeParams service to get the URL parameters. Then in your code you can simply look for `$routeParams.target`and`$routeParams.testvalue` to get the parameter values

Also if you want to monitor the route change, you should subscribe to routeChangeStart event instead of watching 'location.search()'.Look at [How to watch for a route change in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hello, I tried the below code but I am getting both the values as undefined. var App = angular.module('myapp', []);
App.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $routeParams) {
    alert($routeParams.target);
    alert($routeParams.testvalue);
       
});

Comment: May be it takes a while before the route can be known. use a timeout. angular.module('myapp', []); App.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $routeParams, $timeout) { $timeout(function(){alert($routeParams.target); alert($routeParams.testvalue); }, 1000}));

Comment: I tried as suggested by you but still facing the same issue both the values are coming as undefined.

Comment: Hey sorry for not noticing it earlier. But the syntax of query param in your URL is wrong. Fix that and your issues will be gone