# Custome AngularJS route change page with end of animation callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, angularjs-animation

I created animation whitch is run during route change page. Such like Scotch described here http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview

It's very good tut but i need to expand this solution by adding there callbacks on end of animation. I could't find easy way to solve my issue. Could you help me with this ?

Best Regards,
Kuba

Comment: The answer to your question lies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs

maybe set a ng-hide variable with an animation attached

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't answer on my question. I mean the end of the animation, not $locationChangeSuccess.

Comment: I'm looking for the same question too... Still got no answer.

Comment: @Xinan I have not found a solution for this. Maybe in newer version of angular solved problem. Unfortunately, for now only what we have is watching `ng-hide` and `ng-show` classes on elements