# Angular UI Router doesn't get query params on url change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a collection page with a navigation on the left and a bunch of records on the right. Each navigation item corresponds to a record. I want the user to be able to click a nav item on the left and then scroll to the record. Plus the nav item and record should have a 'selected' state.

The URL /stuff/4?selectedRecord=5 should get me all the records of collection id 4 and select record nummer 5.

I got this working with ui-sref on my nav/record items, and the state provider below. When I click on a nav item, the url and states change.

**But when I change the url from /stuff/4?selectedRecord=5 to /stuff/4?selectedRecord=6, nothing happens. No $stateChangeStart is fired...**

```
$stateProvider

    // The stuff index: /stuff
    .state('stuff', {
        url: '/stuff',
        abstract : true,
        templateUrl: 'app/stuff/stuff.html' // wrapper
    })

    // Stuff detail page.
    .state('stuff.detail', {
        url: '/{stuffId}',
        templateUrl: 'app/stuff/stuff.detail.html',
        controller: 'StuffDetailController'
    })

    // Stuff detail page with a record selected
    .state('stuff.detail.selectedRecord', {
        url: '?selectedRecord'
    })
```

This is my sref nav item, which works:

```
<li ui-sref="stuff.detail.selectedRecord({selectedRecord:record.id})"
        ui-sref-active="selected">Works</li>
```

**Edit:** The exact same code works if I change the url of the selectedRecord to:

```
url: '/select/:selectedRecord'
```

Comment: I ran into this exact problem as well. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs) post solved it. I think you need to watch `$routeUpdate`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is, that the url *(`url: '?selectedRecord'`)* defined with question mark at the beginning is the weakest choice for regex... so, if you could have the url e.g. like this:

```
- /stuff/4/?selectedRecord=5  // see the '/' before '?'
- /stuff/4/?selectedRecord=6
```

all will work. In fact, there could be anything, just to help to distinguish that the previous url part *( `url: '/{stuffId}'`)* has been already evaluated.

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYSAmK5GkncZmLHwoJ3C?p=preview), this updated url defintion:

```
.state('stuff.detail.selectedRecord', {
        url: '/?selectedRecord', // the ? is preceeding with /
        ...
    })
```

there could be in fact any other char or combination... just to help to find where the sub state url does start. *(could play around [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYSAmK5GkncZmLHwoJ3C?p=preview))*

Comment: Sometimes you're just a character away... All makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: Great to see that, enjoy `ui-router` ;) great tool ;)