# Is it possible to catch URL changes in browsers address bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting, location

Is it possible from angular or JavaScript to catch URL changes in browser's address bar?

If someone changes the URL in the browser address bar by hand, I want to catch this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also be able to catch it with:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(params) { 
   //catch event
});
```

You can read more about it at [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hi @cbass, $scope.$on could not catch when url changed by manualy

Comment: Well, I mean. If the user presses enter it's probably gonna cause the browser to reload; then also application to reinitialize which means that there is no event to catch.

Comment: You mean there is no way to catch this.

Comment: Yes, if you modify the url and press enter the browser will reload the page. Unless you prevent this is some kind of way.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I have no idea why the OP accepted this.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect changes in the hash (e.g. `http://example.com/#foo`) by creating an event handler like so:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e) { 
    console.log('Hash has changed!'); 
});
```

Specifically to angular, you can use the `$routechangestart` event to catch changes in the URL (i.e. the route)

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    // do something ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can define your routes via the routeProvider and execute specific controllers based on the route that is set.

Comment: listening to hashchange will not work in html5mode. always use $routeChangeStart with angular

Comment: I've added the angular way of doing it, though he asked for either a JS or Angular solution.

Comment: Yes but he has tagged the question with url-rewriting which implies he is going to use html5mode

Comment: My problem is how can I catch when someone change the url in browser's addressbar manually.