# How to redirect in Angular if translate cookie is not set?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-translate

I want to redirect the user to a language page and not allow him to the index page if he hasn't chosen a language yet. I'm using the [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) module. This module has cookie usage built-in with the following function:

```
$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
```

This works. Now I would like to know if this cookie is set, and if not, redirect the user to the language page. Here's my idea how to handle this.

```
.factory('cookiecheck', function(){
  if($translateProvider.CookieStorage.get) return true;
  return false;
}


.run(function($rootScope, $state){

if(cookiecheck
            {$location.path('/language');}
    else
            {$location.path('/home');}
```

This doesn't work. How would I best approach this? What is the correct syntax to determine if a CookieStorage exists and redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your posted code, the factory isn't necessary as you can inject the `$translate` service into your run block.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, $translate) {
    var store = $translate.storage();
    // if store is empty?
    if(angular.equals(store, {}))){
        $location.path('/language');
    }
    else {
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});
```

See [ng-translate docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateCookieStorage) for cookie store

Also, since you won't know if and when the cookie will be expired or removed i think it is best to watch the route for changes and do your check then.

To do that hook into the `$stateChangeStart` event from ui router in your run block

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        // check then redirect
    });
```

[ui router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs) for watching route changes

Comment: The suggestion is good, thank you. But I still need to know the syntax to check if cookie exists, then redirect.

Comment: Hey Harbinger, i updated my answer, i think you want to access the underlying storage and check if its set or not. 

im just not sure what `translate.storage()` returns if there is no language set

Comment: Yes, the translate.storage() was the syntax I was looking for, thank you Dane. This returns an array with get, set and put functions. I'm still looking how to write the redirect to deny a user to type a specific url path and still get redirected to the language page.

Comment: i think the get takes the locale, ie, `$translate.storage().get('en_us')`