# $watch for location.hash changes

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app I am trying to change the location to `"#home"` when the user enters an invalid route.

Here's a short but complete app demonstrating what I did.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $location, $window) {
            $scope.$watch (function() { return $location.url() }, function(url) {
                if (url == '')
                    $window.location = '#home'
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"></body>
</html>
```

But when I do this I get an `infdig` error when the page loads. I don't know whats wrong.

**Edit:**
I don't want to use routing libraries like "ui-router". so answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs) that uses the "angular-route" library are not helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to watch for a route change in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify that in `app.config` block using `$routeProvider`.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      template: 'home.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .otherwise('/home');
});
```

`.otherwise` method will redirect the application to `/home`, if user tries to access any invalid path which is not specified in config.

---

**Update:**

And, If you don't want to use angular routing library you can use native javascript event `hashchange` on window to listen for hash change events. and redirect accordingly.

see the below example.

```js
function locationHashChanged() {
  if (location.hash !== "#/home") {
    console.log('hash is other then #home. will redirect to #home');
    console.log('Full path before', document.URL);
    window.location.hash = '#/home';
    console.log('Full path after', document.URL);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', locationHashChanged);
window.addEventListener('hashchange', locationHashChanged);
```

```html
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<br/>
<a href="#somesite">Some-Site</a>
<br/>
<a href="#other">Other</a>
```

Comment: I think for plain javascript we could use something simple like this,

window.onhashchange = function() { 
var key=window.location.hash;
console.log(key);
switch(key){//do your thing}
}