# How to know the source of the event in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to know the source of the event in angularjs routing. Here is the scenario I am trying to solve. When url changes I want to know whether the change was caused by a browser back button or not.  I thought I can do like this

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function (event) { 
    //if source is back button do this stuff
    // if not do this
});
```

But the event object doesn't have a source information. Did I miss something here? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I believe the params for the function call are function(next, current) - so can you use that to check?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $routeUpdate use '$locationChangeStart'

Here's the discussion about it from the angularjs guys: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2109

Example:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs