# Angular forward slash "/" as state Url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I am trying to achieve here is the following.
I want to create a state Url with just a "/" that will get called no matter what route we are on.
currently not working, am sure I am missing something not sure what exactly.
if someone can help I would appreciate

```
defineState('main', {
            url: "/",
            controller: function () {
                console.log();
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look following answer [How to watch for a route change in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs):

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   ... you could trigger something here ...
});
```

Comment: this works but not when I switch route. ie : /users .  I need a route that is called every time I change views

Comment: If you don't have state with '/users' url it should work.

Comment: If you need to execute something on view change you can listen for route change event, I will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ng-route or ui-router?

with ui-router you can dot this

```
state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });
```

Comment: ui-router. The thing is I dont really have a templateUrl. So I need one. I would really like to have that route called everytime I changed the route

Comment: You don't need template, you can use states with '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")', I will change my sample.