# How do I stop a modal instance from being called when a different controller loads with UI-bootstrap in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implemented a way for my controller to open a ui-bootstrap modal after a specific time. However if I navigate away from the page it will still open. The idea is for the modal to only open after a few minutes on that specific view. How do I stop it when a different controller loads? Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any other code is required.

Here is the code to open that modal:

```
$interval(function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
        });                             
}, 120000, [1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to stop interval using  $interval.cancel(your_interval) on route or state change please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs) for "How to track route or state change?" and go through the [$interval documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) $interval.cancel(). Hope this will solve your problem.