# AngularJS - Use two different controllers?

Tags: angularjs, controller, ngroute

I am starting to play around with AngularJS and I'm not sure about how to update the navigation bar selection. I have 2 things in index.html, the navbar (with the tabs that I need to update) and the div with the ngView.

For the different views, I use ngRoute for changing the templates and attaching a controller to those templates. For the navbar, though, I'm not sure if I should just add "ng-controller="tabController" in the HTML.
This doesn't seem correct, as I am already checking the route for the view, and I would be checking it twice.

Here is my code for the navbar and the div with the view, where the li that has the class "active" should be aligned with the view shown in the div:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="tabController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Recetas Helper</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#/helper">Helper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/insert">Insertar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/randomizer">Randomizer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main-view" ng-view></div>
```

And here is my app.js code, where the controllers are and the route is checked:

```
var app = angular.module('confApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        })
        .when("/helper", {
            templateUrl: "partials/helper.html",
            controller: "helperController"
        })
        .when("/insert", {
            templateUrl: "partials/insert.html"
        })
        .when("/randomizer", {
            templateUrl: "partials/randomizer.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: "partials/ups.html"
        });
});


app.controller('tabController', function($scope) {...});

app.controller('homeController', function($scope) {...});

app.controller('helperController', function($scope) {...});
```

Its the first time I ask a question in SO, so please tell me if there is any important info missing, or the oppossite. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It's not very clear what you want to achieve here, what do you mean exactly by "update the tab selection"? I don't understand this either "I would still need to check the route to change the active tab". Can you edit your question to add precisions? Remember we know nothing about your project, don't hesitate to illustrate what you say with examples of code

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath, I tried to explain it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you are basically using `nav-bar` and changing routes accordingly. Calling it `Tab` would make it more confusing as **TAB** is something different from Navigation Bar. My suggestion:

1. Rename it to `Navigation Controller`
2. If you are using 1.5 and above, create a components as they are better approach for new versions of AngularJS 1.X
3. For the above code you have shared, you can check `$location` and accordingly apply `active` class to the selected `div` using `ng-class`. This will be the only solution as you need to apply `active` class to `div` which will be rendered as per the `routing`

Rest everything looks fine

Comment: Thanks @Shasank Vivek, it worked by using $location, but only the first time I access the page, it doesn't update when the url changes, any idea why?

Comment: in navigationController I have: $scope.url = $location.$$url;      //      and in each li I have ng-class="{active: url == '/helper'}" for each case

Comment: @tonyjojo: yes, it happens because the contoller is already loaded and so it holds the `$location` data of it's first load. For your situation, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs . You need to capture the event when route is changed

Comment: Thanks again @Shashank Vivek!