# show the page names dynamically for all pages to index.html

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

in our project we ha multiple pages in .
i want to show the particular view name on my layout view.
for example my path is http://localhost:64632/admin/index.html#/Subscribe. then the "subscribe" name should shou on main view. i want this code using javascript.
asp.net C# javascript, webapi

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current url by using javascript:

```
var x = window.location.href;
```

If you want the string after the '#/' you could use the following

```
var x = window.location.href.split('#/')[1];
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. its working fine, but the value of x is loading when the page refresh only. this is my index view  <li><h5 class="page-title">{{pagetitle}}</h5></li>

Comment: my js is var page = window.location.href.split('#/')[1];   $scope.pagetitle = page;

Comment: it should change the title name when i click the menu. but its not changing. when i refresh the entire page then only its changing the page title as per i want. what should i do? please help me.

Comment: Instead "window.location.href" use "$location.absUrl()". You need to inject '$location' just like '$scope'

Comment: This is also working same as previous. index.js is not reloading. without reloading i need to get the changed path.

Comment: well it all depends on the framework you are using but since you have interpolation i guess you are using angular(JS)?. The example of @vijayliebe is correct in AngularJS but you would still have to subscribe to the page change event  otherwise your code doesn't run again (e.g. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs)