# What's the difference between $locationChangeSuccess and $locationChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, window.location

What's the difference between `$locationChangeSuccess` and `$locationChangeStart`?

They are both undocumented events related to `window.location`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `$locationChangeStart` is fired when AngularJS starts to update browser's location based on mutations done via `$location` service (`$location.path()`, `$location.search()`).

It might happen that an application will listen to the `$locationChangeStart` event and will call `preventDefault()` on it. In this case the second event (`$locationChangeSuccess`) won't be broadcasting.

In short: `$locationChangeStart` fires when the location gets updated. It is followed by `$locationChangeSuccess` if the first action wasn't prevented.

Relevant bits of the source code are here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2508b47c1a34dfc834f8fde858574f81af4d287e/src/ng/location.js#L598