# Need a common layout accross pages while building a site using angularjs and twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am building a site using AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap. The site I am building have 10 pages and in each pages I want to used a reusable common layout for navigation bar.The concept is like master page in ASP.net or layout in MVC.But there is no such concept in AngularJS or HTML5. So how can I achieve that.Please provide links of some example.

Thanks and Regards

Utpal Maity

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291866/master-page-concept-in-angularjs
Or use ui.router where you can have multiple `ui-view`s

Comment: I dont want to add multiple view I wan a common layout accross view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include partials for your navigation with [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)